# CSS transform animation crashes

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have an issue but can't find where I made a mistake...
I made an little animation using transform in CSS as you can see on the code.
But sometimes when I hover the mouse the animation becomes crazy. I feel like it occurs often when I hover from bottom left to right.
Wonder is you can see it.
Can you help me fix it please ?

```css
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    } 

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #ccc;
    }

    .container{
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .carre{
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #63aace;
        border: 3px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    }

    .carre__front{
        position: absolute;
        width: 180px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 7px;
        top: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #c65d5d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .carre__tippy{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 60px;
        left: 47px;
        bottom: 70px;
        border: 2px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .description{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        opacity: .9;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .carre:hover{
        transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(30deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-20deg) translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(100px);
        box-shadow: -100px 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    .carre:hover .carre__front{
        transform: translateZ(50px);
        box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        opacity: .7;
    }

    .carre:hover .carre__tippy{
        transform: perspective(0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(120px);
        box-shadow: -50px 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <!-- En-tête de la page -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>titre</title>
    </head>


    <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="carre">  
            <div class="carre__front"> 
               
            </div>
            <div class="carre__tippy">  
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="description"><p>Information display</p></div> 
    </div>
   

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't mention anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the `perspective`. You have to set it on the parent (so `perspective: 1000px;` inside `.container`) and remove the others.

It might still 'flicker' a bit since it's transforming and calculating if your mouse is still hovering the element. (When it moves, the elements actually move out from underneath the mouse's position sometimes and then the `:hover` rules don't apply and the transforms reverse, coming back under the mouse triggering `:hover`, and so on..)

```css
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    } 

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #ccc;
    }

    .container{
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        position: relative;
        perspective: 1000px;
    }

    .carre{
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #63aace;
        border: 3px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    }

    .carre__front{
        position: absolute;
        width: 180px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 7px;
        top: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #c65d5d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .carre__tippy{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 60px;
        left: 47px;
        bottom: 70px;
        border: 2px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .description{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        opacity: .9;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .carre:hover{
        transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-20deg) translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(100px);
        box-shadow: -100px 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    .carre:hover .carre__front{
        transform: translateZ(50px);
        box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        opacity: .7;
    }

    .carre:hover .carre__tippy{
        transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(120px);
        box-shadow: -50px 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="container">
        <div class="carre">  
            <div class="carre__front"></div>
            <div class="carre__tippy"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="description"><p>Information display</p></div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed there still is some flickering. I think I can fix it ;)

Comment: You could set the `:hover` rule on a parent element that doesn't move/change, like a wrapper.

Comment: You removed the flickering but also the perspective effect. Perspective must be added on the parent container and it will affect all the children in the same maner.

Comment: @lulius I believe all elements needed the same perspective, so there's no need for other perspective declarations on the child elements

Comment: @Philip I don't think you understood me. Yes all the elements needed the same perspective and that's why you place it on the parent (in his case the ".container" div). If you run your code snippet and his original one you will see yours does not have perspective.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I made a mistake. Changed my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Philip and lulius for the follow up. I set the hover on a different element and it works perfectly, no more flickering :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your perspective out of the :hover in css. It'll work.

```
.carre:hover{
    transform:  rotateX(30deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-20deg) translateX(0) 
                translateY(0) translateZ(100px);
    box-shadow: -100px 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  .carre__tippy{
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(120px);
    box-shadow: -50px 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }
  .carre__front{
    transform: translateZ(50px);
    box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    opacity: .7;
   }
}
```

Here I nested all your css together for track keeping a little easier
Edit: I meant SCSS file not CSS.

Comment: You can't nest classes like that in css. This is preprocessor syntax (scss, less etc.)

Comment: It is indeed SCSS file. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Remove perspective from all the transformations and place it on the container (not on hover).

"When defining the perspective property for an element, it is the CHILD elements that get the perspective view, NOT the element itself."

In your case the parent element is ".container" since you're applying some transformations to ".carre" too.

```css
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    } 

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #ccc;
    }

    .container{
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        position: relative;
        perspective: 1000px;
    }

    .carre{
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #63aace;
        border: 3px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    }

    .carre__front{
        position: absolute;
        width: 180px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 7px;
        top: 50px;
        border: 2px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #c65d5d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .carre__tippy{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 60px;
        left: 47px;
        bottom: 70px;
        border: 2px solid #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all ease 1s;
        opacity: .9;
    }

    .description{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        opacity: .9;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .carre:hover{
        transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-20deg) translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(100px);
        box-shadow: -100px 100px 100px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    .carre:hover .carre__front{
        transform: translateZ(50px);
        box-shadow: -20px 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        opacity: .7;
    }

    .carre:hover .carre__tippy{
        transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(120px);
        box-shadow: -50px 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }

    p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <!-- En-tête de la page -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>titre</title>
    </head>


    <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="carre">  
            <div class="carre__front"> 
               
            </div>
            <div class="carre__tippy">  
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="description"><p>Information display</p></div> 
    </div>
   

    </body>
</html>
```